# preserve specific characters with janitor clean_names

Tags: r, janitor

I am using `janitor` `clean_names()`/`make_clean_names()` and would like to preserve certain characters. I think `replace` is the argument I should be using and that works for some cases. For example, I can replace dashes with zeros:

```
> janitor::make_clean_names("x-x", replace = c(`-` = "0"))
[1] "x0x"
```

However, there does not seem to be a way to keep dashes (or other special characters):

```
> janitor::make_clean_names("x-x", replace = c(`-` = "-"))
[1] "x_x"
```

Comment: @akrun. Please post as answer!

Answer (score 1):

One of the main reasons to use `make_clean_names` is to return a standard name that can be parsed without having to use backquotes. The package uses `_` as default replacement when there is a non-standard character.  Therefore, even if we provide a named `vector` in the `replace`, it will be changed in the code to `_` as the documentation says the order of operations as

> The order of operations is: make replacements, (optional) ASCII conversion, remove initial spaces and punctuation, apply base::make.names(), apply snakecase::to_any_case, and add numeric suffixes to resolve any duplicated names.

```
janitor::make_clean_names("x-x", replace = c(`-` = "~"), use_make_names = FALSE)
[1] "x_x"
janitor::make_clean_names("x-x", replace = c(`-` = "-"), use_make_names = FALSE)
[1] "x_x"
```

An option is to specify the `sep_out` to return a character of interest

```
janitor::make_clean_names("x-x",  sep_out = "-")
[1] "x-x"
janitor::make_clean_names("x-x",  sep_out = "~")
[1] "x~x"
```

---

An option to preserve the non-standard character using `make_clean_names` would be to replace with a unique standard character and then replace the unique character/words later

```
gsub("_change_", "-", janitor::make_clean_names("x-x:x~x", 
    replace = c(`-` = "_change_")))
[1] "x-x_x_x"
```

Comment: This would replace all problematic characters with "-". I just want to preserve existing "-", not introduce new ones.